# How to send data while deep linking to an android app

Tags: android, deep-linking

I want to enable the feature of deep linking to my app. My app's intent filter should  receive the event which should have latitude (double) and longitude (double) information. based on these values, it will launch the mapview with the location denoted by latitude and longitude values.

This is what I have tried so far:

From another app, I am sending the intent in this fashion :

```
String requestedLatitude = "48.8584";
String requestedLongitude = "2.2945";
String uri = "myapp://nearby?lat=" + requestedLatitude + "&lon=" + requestedLongitude;
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
startActivity(intent);
```

This is how I am trying to write intent filter:

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/intent_nearby_label">
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <data android:scheme="myapp"
  android:host="nearby" />
</intent-filter>
```

I am not sure how to make this intent filter to receive latitude and longitude values and how to get them in my app.

I want to add a similar feature as this app:

https://www.developers.moovitapp.com/deeplinking-your-app

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

To do deep linking you don't need to add a filter unless you want to make the functionality public.

In either cases, just start the main application of your app with those extras in the intent.

Then in the onCreate() mehtod get the `Intent` with `getIntent()` and check for the parameters.

If they are there start your mapview activity.

If going back you need to go to the main activity of your app, you will have to adjust the Back Stack.

References:
[Tasks and Back Stack](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html)
[Deep Linking](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to make the functionality public, so want to write the intent filter to receive intents with the URL format which has latitude and longitude information.